# Can I register Worker Factory for WorkManager other than in the Application?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

When we implementing a custom `WorkerFactory`, we have to register our Factory in our custom configuration `Application()`. Is there any other way to register a WorkerFactory elsewhere? Because I do not want to change the code that is in `Application()`.

For example by using Lazy implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can use `initialize()` for on-demand initialization. But, it has a side effect. It can cause delays on some Work Manager features.